# Running CartoDB Server Stack?

Tags: carto, installation, server, ruby

We're attempting to download and run the CartoDB stack on an Ubuntu Amazon EC2 instance dedicated just for it. So we've begun from a bare bones OS install.

We've gone through the install/configure README (https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb) and got through most of it without too much of an issue. But when it comes time to figuring out how to actually **run** the thing, we're at a loss. The readme doesn't even seem to explain how you're supposed to run the stack perpetually as a service, or even as separate components side-by-side.

The closest it seems to come is suggesting foreman but even that has come to a convoluted cluster**** of dependency issues to where I can't even add it to the gem bundle as described (and it doesn't help none of us have Ruby experience)

Do you have any pointers on where to go from here?

Even Google is utterly failing me at this point.

Comment: In the guide you have all you need to run the services that CartoDB is composed of at [Running CartoDB section](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb#running-cartodb), and you can "run the stack perpetually as a service" by using that commands with Linux services just like you would with any other software. Maybe if you give more details about your Foreman issues Foreman community or us might help.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. We'd wiped the instance started over by the time I saw the reply so couldn't respond. We've since wiped *again* and went to a 12.04 install, referencing two different walkthroughs and have got things mostly set up and foreman working, but I still don't see how to run things perpetually. Even "bundle exec foreman start -p 3000" sticks you in a process. If I CTRL-C out at the very least resque and thin shut down.

Of course I can use & to run everything in the background but that still doesn't provide a clean way to shut everything down, restart, or recover on error.

Answer (score 2):

README is mostly oriented to set up a development environment. Foreman is just a helper to run all services you need in the same window without having several terminals.

If you want to run the services perpetually I suggest you to run all services as daemons.

You can check the Procfile in the root of cartodb repository and you will find the commands Foreman really starts.

You have two options:

1. The dirty way is running every command in a screen/tmux tab and detach
2. The clean way is that you create a ubuntu upstart init script for every service and let upstart to run them.

Notice that redis server should be properly configured so it have disk persistence.